# I want to know how to deploy the war file in apache tomcat and make it to run

Tags: apache, tomcat, ant

I create a war file using apache ant and 
i wanted to
deploy that .war file in tomcat and make it run
can u people help me with the steps..
i m not clear abt it

Answer (score 3):

- stop tomcat
- move your war into [tomcat install dir]/webapps
- start tomcat

tomcat will deploy the war on startup

Answer (score 0):

1. for database connectivity copy the connector in the lib folder of project which is in WEB_INF folder
   like point\war\WEB-INF\lib
2. create war File ...in war folder of the project
   like c:/user/workspace/point/war/  there (point is project name)
   ...by command jar cvf point.war *
3. now type `http://localhost/portnumber/` like mine is `http://localhost/9090`
4. press on tomcat manager and give user and password
5. go on the option deploy war file to upload ...browse and choice the war file create in war folder of project
   upload the file
6. click on the /point which created by manager and their your file is uploaded

Comment: if any problem i can help you more ..have a nice day